# TSLint - indent using spaces not highlightening any errors

Tags: angular, indentation, tslint

I am trying to define "indent" rule in my tslint.json following [this](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/indent/) tslint documentation for indent. But it is working only for "tabs" option. I want to use spaces for indentation.
Below is my tslint.json (minimised for readability):

```
{
  "extends": [
    "tslint:recommended"
  ],
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
  ],
  "rules": {
    ...
    "indent": [true, "spaces", 2]
  }
}
```

According to Documentation, the above rule should produce error for the following indention of my .ts file:

```
activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
  this.id = params.id;
       this._fetch(this.id, this.params); //this should produce error due to wrong indentation 
});
```

I have seen following issue on their github account but still can't figure it out why tslint is not throwing any error for this indentation.
https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/2814

**Note:** I am using tslint v5.11.0